# Using C function in a assembly code (nasm)

Tags: assembly

I am trying to use a c function in my assembly code. So what my code does is to call a subroutine named "shift". This subroutine will call my c function "changeLetter" this function shifts a letter so if I send letter "a" with number of shift 3 then will return "d". However, when I run my function it returns null.

main.asm

```
extern printf, scanf
extern shift
global _start

section .data


format3 db "%s ",0
message5:     db "Message is :",10,0
original: db "Hello World.",10,0

len1:  equ  $ - original


section .text
        global  main


main:


        mov rsi, message5
        call messages


        mov r8,original         ;moving to my register message to be shifted 
        mov rsi, len1           ;length of message
        call shift          ;calling subroutine

        mov rsi, r8         ;moving new message to my register to be printed
        call messages

        ret


messages:
        mov rdi,format3
        mov rdx,rsi
        mov rax,0
        call printf
        ret
```

shift.asm

```
global shift
extern changeLetter ;my c function

section .text

shift:

        mov rdx, rsi            ;rdx length of string                                                                                                                                                       

        mov rcx,0
loop:   cmp rcx, rdx
        jge done

        mov rdi, [r8 +rcx]      ;character to be shifted                                                                                                                                                    
        mov rsi,  3             ;number of shifts                                                                                                                                                           
        call changeLetter
        mov [r8 + rcx], rax     ;replace the character                                                                                                                                                      
        inc rcx

        jmp loop

done:
        ret
```

changeLetter.c

```
char changeLetter(char letter, int numOfShifts) 
{

return letter + numOfShifts;

}
```

Comment: I see a `call encrypt` but no `call changeLetter`

Comment: @ecm it was a misspelling I just corrected

Comment: most amd64 calling conventions consider %rcx and %r8 to be volatile; thus your c function may change them before returning.   So after your call to `shift -> changeLettter`, %r8 may be dead.

Comment: You mention changing _characters_, but you load and store 8 bytes at a time (`mov rdi, [r8 +rcx]`). This potentially writes garbage in the 7 bytes after the one character, and will write past the end of the space you've allocated for `original`.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm so how do I fix that? How do I move only one character to rdi and then move this character after shifting to my final string?

Comment: One possibility is `movzx rdi,byte ptr [r8+rcx]`, then `mov [r8 + rcx], al`.